# Where do I find previous employer in a DS 160 form?

Tags: usa

I have already filled out the DS 160 form but I am wondering why it doesn't have the option of previous work / travel. It only asks the present and the next page is already security background. I was wondering if I have missed something that that page does not show. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such field in the DS-160 form. It only asks you about your current job, not every job you've ever held.